# TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've Navigate to next page and then Navigate back in windows phone 8, If 5 or 6 times i do this app is crashed and output windows shows "TaskHost.exe has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313)". I don't know why this is happening. If anybody knows please suggest me. It is very argent.

//////////////// MainPage /////////////////

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            App app=App.Current as App;
            if (app.IsFromFavouritePage)
            {
                    ShowStoryboard.Begin();
                    app.IsFromFavouritePage = false;
                    MainViewModel mvm = DataContext as MainViewModel;
                    mvm.RingtoneCollection.Clear();
                    mvm.RingtoneCollection = CheckFavouriteRingtone(app.CollectionOfRingtone, app.CollectionOfRingtone[0].category_ringtone_id.ToString());
                    ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;

            }

        }

    private void favListButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainViewModel mvm = DataContext as MainViewModel;
            App app = App.Current as App;
            app.CollectionOfRingtone.Clear();
            foreach (RingtoneClass aRingtone in mvm.RingtoneCollection)
            {
                app.CollectionOfRingtone.Add(aRingtone);
            }
            List<RingtoneClass> listOfFavouriteRingtone = SelectAllFromDb();
            if (listOfFavouriteRingtone != null && listOfFavouriteRingtone.Count > 0)
            {
                app.IsPopular = IsPopular;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/FavouritePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

        }

///////////////// NEXT PAGE (FavouritePage) ///////////////////////////////////////////

private void backImageButton_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            app = App.Current as App;
            app.IsFromFavouritePage = true;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));         
        }

        protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
            app = App.Current as App;
            app.IsFromFavouritePage = true;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }
```

**//////////////////// OUTPUT FROM DEBUG /////////////**
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\WebBrowserControlRes.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\WebBrowserControlRes.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Loaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'TaskHost.exe' (Win32): Unloaded '\Device\HarddiskVolume27\Windows\System32\UIXMobileAssets480x800.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: LegacyHelper::ApiException at memory location 0x0C57F658.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: LegacyHelper::ApiException at memory location 0x0C57F230.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB (KERNELBASE.DLL) in TaskHost.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131501, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x70150000).
The thread 0xe34 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0C57D7A8.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0C57D498.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0C57D188.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0C57DAD0.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptExceptionObject at memory location 0x0C57EBF8.
First-chance exception at 0x76FC1EDB in TaskHost.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: LegacyHelper::ApiException at memory location 0x0C57DF08.
The thread 0xe08 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x7b0 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf18 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x424 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x2a8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x960 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xab4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xdc has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x200 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xe78 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf4c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf68 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x6a8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf34 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x294 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xb50 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf54 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x838 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xea8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x7dc has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xb30 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x10c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x40c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xd44 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x658 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x210 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xc64 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xbc4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf58 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xd68 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xdc4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x9ac has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x378 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x618 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x434 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x78 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xef8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf5c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x880 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x958 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x898 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xbd8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x978 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xc8c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xd54 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xc68 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xcf4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xfb4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xc7c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x2b4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf94 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x30 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf84 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xa54 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x820 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x92c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x1a8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xe0c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xd28 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xa00 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf38 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xd70 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xdd4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf50 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x9cc has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xb0c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x3e4 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x8c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xcc8 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0x848 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xb04 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xf90 has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The thread 0xe6c has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).
The program '[3700] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -2147220717 (0x80040313).

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: On your next page are you playing audio(ring tune)? also your main page contain starts a storyboard which might me causing the the issue. try these

1. stop playing audio(if you are playing it) in your 2nd page when leaving the page.

2. stop story board while you are leaving the first page. 

this might help

Comment: Did it worked for you?

Comment: @Muhammad Saifullah I've already tried by removing storyboard and without playing ringtone. One thing i can say used sqlite-net-wp8 to store favorite ringtone that shows in next page.

Comment: can you sure your sqlite code used in 2nd page